# autocomplete working only once?

Tags: jquery-mobile

I've tried many different autocomplete scripts - everytime the same error...
using a link or something else from page a to page b and autocomplete is not working anymore...

I have source like this

PAGE A
....

```
<script src="css/jqm.autoComplete-1.5.1-min.js"></script>

<div data-role="page" id="PAGE A" data-theme="a"   >    
<div data-role="header"  data-id="header" data-position="fixed">
<input type="text" id="searchbox" placeholder="Suchbegriffe..." data-filter-theme="a">
</div>

<div data-role="content" >
<ul  id="autocomplete_displ" data-role="listview"  data-inset="true" style="margin-top: -20px;margin-  bottom: 10px;" data-filter-theme="a"></ul>
</div>

</div>      

<script>
    $("#PAGE A").on("pageshow", function(e) {

        $("#searchbox").autocomplete({
            target: $('#autocomplete_displ'),
            source: '../json.asp',
            link: 'list_titles.asp?searchstring=',
            minLength: 1
        });
    });
```

PAGE B
....

```
<script src="css/jqm.autoComplete-1.5.1-min.js"></script>

<div data-role="page" id="PAGE B" data-theme="a"   >    
<div data-role="header"  data-id="header" data-position="fixed">
<input type="text" id="searchbox" placeholder="Suchbegriffe..." data-filter-theme="a">
</div>

<div data-role="content" >
<ul  id="autocomplete_displ" data-role="listview"  data-inset="true" style="margin-top: -20px;margin- bottom: 10px;" data-filter-theme="a"></ul>
</div>

</div>      

<script>
    $("PAGE B").on("pageshow", function(e) {

        $("#searchbox").autocomplete({
            target: $('#autocomplete_displ'),
            source: '../json.asp',
            link: 'list_titles.asp?searchstring=',
            minLength: 1
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

solved the problem moving the js in the header - when the inputfield of the autocomplete is in the header...